# Meteor routing params and database query

Tags: meteor

I am brand new to Meteor (just 2 days in and also new to Mongo and the whole stack), so please bear with me. I am laying out high level design patterns for an application at this point. 
One of the things I will need to do is allow users to specify a URL (e.g.  http://meteor.example.co/XXXXX2016) and then get the document from the database where one of the fields (that is not the ID) is equal to the XXXXX2016 part of the URL.

Based on what I think so far, one way way to deal with this seems to be:
1) Have the XXXXX2016 be a route parameter (most likely going to use Iron Router for routing)
2) Have the client query for that document (or is there a way to do this with pub/sub that is better?)
3) Update the templates with the data form that document (and eventually related and sub documents).

That parameter from the URL (or route) controls the banner logo for every sub-"page" along with many other things and is the catalyst of the entry point when within the app. Am I moving in the correct general direction or are there other approaches/considerations I should look into before moving forward?

I am not sure if this should more client or server oriented or how best to structure this sort of paradigm in Meteor.

I also know this could be considered somewhat of a broad, open ended question/answer. But I would like to hear any any feedback from more experienced Meteor peers if they are willing to share.

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's two ways:

Code in:

`/lib` runs on both client and server

`/server` runs only on server

`/client` runs only on client

- Create DB Collection in `/lib`.
- Iron Router reads the params from the URL for a particular route.
- IR takes this param and does a DB subscription.
- Write a corresponding Publish function in `/server` for this subscription.
- In the template JS you can directly access the DB collection since the route is now subscribed to it.

OR

- Create DB Collection in `/lib`.
- Subscribe to DB Collection in Iron Router, which is in `/lib`.
- Write a corresponding Publish function in `/server` for this subscription.
- Iron Router reads the params from the URL for a particular path/route.
- IR takes this param and does a DB query, bringing back either a cursor or array of objects.
- IR sets the `data` context of the route using the info above.
- In the template JS for your route you can then access the data and do functions with the data returned from Iron Router - just search around for how to use the route's data context in your template callbacks.

Comment: Wow I actually got all that! Thanks... that gives me the base I needed.